# Treeview not showing my children

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I've not used the TreeView before other than in a few tutorials to get the hang of them. I thought I had, it turns out I haven't.

I'm trying to bind my TreeView to an object.

The Object is

```
public List<MyGrandparents> MyGrandParents {get;set;}
```

Within the MyGrandParent class, there is a property

```
public List<MyParents> MyParents{get;set;}
```

and lastly, within the MyParent class there is a property

```
public List<MyChildren> MyChildren {get;set;}
```

Within each class, there are other properties such as Name (no base classes though so no shared code at this stage)

I want to bind the lot to a tree view, so at 'root' level I only see grandparents. I can expand grandparents to only see parents, whom I can also expand to see children.

The issue I have is only the highest level is binding (grandparent level). My XAML is

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding MyGrandParents}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyGrandParent}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
            </DataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyParent}" ItemsSource="{Binding MyGrandParents}">
                    <TextBlock Text="Don't bind to test"></TextBlock>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>            
    </TreeView>
```

I am lost as to why this isn't binding to give me a nice Tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not following correct pattern to use `HierarchicalDataTemplate`.

Item which might `contain children` should be declare as `HierarchicalDataTemplate` with `ItemsSource` set to `child collection` you want to show beneath it.

And `item not containing any child` should be declare as `DataTemplate` instead.

It should be like this -

```
<TreeView.Resources>
   <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyGrandParent}"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding MyParents}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
   </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
   <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyParent}"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding MyChildren}">
        <TextBlock Text="Don't bind to test"></TextBlock>
   </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyChildren}">
        <TextBlock Text="Don't bind to test"></TextBlock>
   </DataTemplate>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

Comment: Am I attempting this backwards? Children is the lowest level, yet in your example, it *appears* to be the highest level? Is the DataTemplate the 'root' and all HierarchicalDataTemplates the children?

Comment: Updated answer with explanation. Have a look.

Comment: Thank you! I've been reading through tutorials for the past hour, but none of them explained the use of `TreeView` this clearly.