# Dynamically display TreeViewItem children

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I have a WPF application with a `TreeView`. I drag and drop files and/or folders onto this `TreeView`. In the case that the dragged item is a folder, which I have set up to detect, I search the top level of this directory.

Where I am stuck is in displaying these inner files on the `TreeView`. I wish for these inner files to be displayed as children of the folder item.

This is the class to model an item in the TreeView:

```
public class FileList
{
    public enum FileType { File, Folder };

    public FileType Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<FileList> innerFiles;
    public ObservableCollection<FileList> InnerFiles
    {
        get
        {

            return innerFiles;
        }
        set
        {
            innerFiles = value;
        }
    }

    public FileList(string file)
    {
        Name = file;
        Type = FolderOrFile(file);
    }
}
```

This is the xaml code within `TreeView.ItemTemplate`

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
        <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Name="mnuExpand" Header="Expand" Click="mnuExpand_Click" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
     </TextBlock>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding InnerFiles}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>

</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

I assign an `ObservableCollection` of `FileList` objects to the inner collection in the `TreeViewItem`'s `FileList` and then refresh the grid, but these children items do not appear.

I tried following: [TreeView not showing my Children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20175788/treeview-not-showing-my-children)

However I want the potential to open/search as many levels down as possible.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` what object the source for the child items is using the `ItemsSource` property. Try this instead:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding InnerFiles}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"> <!-- DataTemplate for parent -->
        <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Name="mnuExpand" Header="Expand" Click="mnuExpand_Click" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
    </TextBlock>    
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate> <!-- DataTemplate for children -->
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>    
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

See the [`HierarchicalDataTemplate` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN for more information.

Comment: Thank you! This has been a great help. I can now display the child files. The only issue I have now is that I cannot display the name of the parent. I colour each top item to identify whether it's a file or folder, which is visible, but I do not see the name text. I cannot use `DisplayMemberPath` as the ItemTemplate is set.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I seem to have got your templates mixed up. I edited my answer, so see if that's any better for you.

Comment: That's great thanks. I don't see however how the datatemplate works for the parent as it's defined within `<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding InnerFiles}">`

Comment: A [`HierarchicalDataTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate(v=vs.110).aspx) *is* a `DataTemplate`... it extends the `DataTemplate` class.